# Unexplained Gap in SwiftUI View

Tags: swiftui

I am seeing a white line between two of my view elements, that I cannot explain.  [image: Filtered List View]

The following cod is the main SwiftUI View

```
 var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            TextField("Filter", text: $lastNameFilter)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing, .bottom])
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
            FilteredList(filter: lastNameFilter)
        } }
```

The FilteredList view is very simple:

```
    var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(fetchRequest, id: \.self) { recipient in
            NavigationLink(destination:
                            ViewEventsView(recipient: recipient)) {
                Text("\(recipient.wrappedFirstName) \(recipient.wrappedLastName)")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteRecipient)
    }
}
```

I have tried with and without padding, but that is not the issue.  The .padding, is adjusting the inset of the "filter" TextField.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably the default spacing of the VStack. Try changing it to `VStack(spacing: 0)`.